# Convert a text file into a large dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
subjects ENGLISH, MATHS, SCIENCE

Joe, A, A, B

Dave, A, B, C

Will, D, D, E
```

And I want to put it into a dictionary using Python

```
{’Joe’:{’ENGLISH’:A,’MATHS’:A,’SCIENCE’:B},
’Dave’:{’ENGLISH’:A,’MATHS’:B,’SCIENCE’:C},
’Will’:{’ENGLISH’:D,’MATHS’:D,’SCIENCE’:E}}
```

How would I go about doing this in one dictionary?

Comment: That looks like standard CSV format, for which Python even ships with builtin parser. What trouble do you have using such tools for the task?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a file called `file.txt` with the following contents:

```
subjects ENGLISH, MATHS, SCIENCE

Joe, A, A, B

Dave, A, B, C

Will, D, D, E
```

Try using `*` unpacking:

```
results = {}
with open('file.txt') as file:
    _, *subjects = next(file).split(' ')  # Read header row
    subjects = [s[:-1] for s in subjects]  # Remove trailing comma/newline from subjects
    for line in file:
        if line != '\n':  # Skip empty lines
            name, *grades = line.strip().split(', ')
            results[name] = dict(zip(subjects, grades))
print(results)
```

You can also define the subjects in code and skip the header row completely:

```
subjects = ['ENGLISH', 'MATHS', 'SCIENCE']
results = {}
with open('file.txt') as file:
    next(file)  # Skip header row since we have defined subjects in code...
    for line in file:
        if line != '\n':  # Skip empty lines
            name, *grades = line.strip().split(', ')
            results[name] = dict(zip(subjects, grades))
print(results)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Joe': {'ENGLISH': 'A', 'MATHS': 'A', 'SCIENCE': 'B'}, 'Dave': {'ENGLISH': 'A', 'MATHS': 'B', 'SCIENCE': 'C'}, 'Will': {'ENGLISH': 'D', 'MATHS': 'D', 'SCIENCE': 'E'}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if the subjects were standard so we could in theory remove that line and have the same output how would that work?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard"?

Comment: So instead of getting the subjects from the text file. We can assume the subjects in the code if that makes sense

Comment: @Anthillion Is my update to the answer what you mean?

Comment: Yes it is thank you so much. Also is there anyway to get rid of the apostrophes on the letters so instead of 'A' its just A?

Answer (score 0):

We can read the file by using `pd.read_csv()` and convert the `pd` to a dictionary by using: `df.to_dict('index')`

Answer (score -1):

You could convert your text file to CSV

```
Name, ENGLISH, MATHS, SCIENCE

Joe, A, A, B

Dave, A, B, C

Will, D, D, E
```

Then use the pandas' library to read the CSV file and convert it into the dictionary.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv('file_path.csv',index_col='Name').transpose().to_dict()
```

{'Joe': {'ENGLISH': ' A', 'MATHS': ' A', 'SCIENCE': ' B'}, 'Dave': {'ENGLISH': ' A', 'MATHS': ' B', 'SCIENCE': ' C'}, 'Will': {'ENGLISH': ' D', 'MATHS': ' D', 'SCIENCE': ' E'}}

Comment: I can't change it to a CSV but is there a way in panda to it via a text file